# how i can get response outside the function, Inside function response getting

Tags: angularjs

In console undefined message getting. How i can get fast response and how i will use callback function.

service -----

```
.factory('getUserInfo', function ($http) {
    return {
        init: function () {
            return $http.get(base_url + 'User/getUserInfo', {
            }).then(function (response) {
                return response.data.data;
            });

        },
    };
});
```

coltrollers -----

```
$scope.getUserInfo = function () {
            getUserInfo.init().then(function (response) {
                $scope.USER_UAD_response = response;
                $scope.USER_UAD_SYS_ID = response.USER_UAD_SYS_ID;
                //$scope.getPrice();
            });
        };
        $scope.getUserInfo();
    console.log($scope.USER_UAD_response);
```

Comment: I am  not understand

Comment: keep `console.log` **inside** `.then(...)`

Answer (score 0):

You are making an asynchronous call, so need to move your `console.log` into `.then` function. The reason behind this is `console.log` is the next statement which will execute after `$scope.getUserInfo();`. Before getting the response from HTTP service console.log will get executed and you are getting `undefined` as output.

Directly return promise from factory service and move the code that you want to execute after service call into `.then` method.

service -----

```
.factory('getUserInfo', function ($http) {
    return {
        init: function () {
            return $http.get(base_url + 'User/getUserInfo');    
        }
    };
});
```

controller -----

```
$scope.getUserInfo = function () {
            getUserInfo.init().then(function (response) {
                $scope.USER_UAD_response = response;
                $scope.USER_UAD_SYS_ID = response.USER_UAD_SYS_ID;
                //$scope.getPrice();
                console.log($scope.USER_UAD_response);

            });
        };
        $scope.getUserInfo();
```